# Cannot leave page because of validators

Tags: asp.net, validation

I have a problem, with my validators.
I have validation on a contactform, to ensure spam, but my problem is, when I go to the page and want to go back to the default site, it won't let me, because of the validators. Nothing has been written in the textboxes and the "Send" button hasn't been clicked.

Anyone who have an idea, for what I can do?

Comment: going back with default browser button or you have some other button in page to go back?

Answer (score 3):

If you are going "back" with a specific button instead of the browser's back button, set `CausesValidation="false"` in the attributes of the button.

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to a **button / any other submitting control** you click to go back which has [**CausesValidation**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.causesvalidation.aspx) set to true? This property will cause all your validatorControls to perform a check and as a consequence, if there is any invalid control/value prevent the user from changing page.

Hitting the *Back-Button in your browser* is possible at any time and cannot be prevented by a validatorControl.

Comment: I have a button on the page to go back with, a simple "Home" button.
The same problem happens, when I use any other links on the page.

Comment: check the `CausesValidation` property of this button and set it to **false** - this should do the trick!

Comment: Actually, it isn't really a button, its just a <a href="default">Home</a> .. Are there any CausesValidation on those?

Comment: pure html links cannot cause this behaviour. Perhaps it is a linkButton - which could cause the failure. You could post your aspx code so we can help!

Comment: Pilgerstorfer, I would if I could, but it is an final project in school, so I am not allowed to take the project with me, I can only work on it at school. But it is an simple <a href=""> tag.

Comment: Until we get some piece of code, we won't be able to help you. Check the answers given and I am almost convinced your problem will get solved!

Comment: I just tried making a new site at home with a contactform with validators on and a simple <a href="#">, and here there is no problem. Thats strange!